# Trouble getting one-time user location in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am trying to get the user's location at the time of a button press, however I am having trouble setting up the location code. I've been looking between various answers on Stackoverflow but I can't get anything to work for me.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .AuthorizedAlways || status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        let latitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude
        print("coordinates:")
        print(latitude)
        print(longitude)
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let locationValue : CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    print("locations = \(locationValue.latitude) \(locationValue.longitude)")
}
```

However I just get nils from the prints in `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` and nothing ever prints from `didUpdateLocations`. Im also really confused about where to put `startUpdatingLocation()`. Some answers place it directly in `viewDidLoad` as I have here, others place it in `didChangeAuthorizationStatus`, and I saw another place it inside an `if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()` in didLoad. What is the correct way to do this? And also what have I done wrong that I'm not getting any values printing? I'm running on the emulator, have location turned on and allowed permissions in the pop-up, and have the emulator set to a lat/long custom location, and I have added the values in pList.

edit: [even tried copy/pasting the code from this to get user's location only once](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/location/how-to-request-a-users-location-only-once-using-requestlocation) but it returns `(kCLErrorDomain error 0.)`. I added a 'requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` to their code but it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

> get nils from the prints in didChangeAuthorizationStatus

Because we don't have any locations yet. That's the wrong place to ask for that information. All that happened is that we are now authorized.

> nothing ever prints from didUpdateLocations

Because you're running on the simulator, perhaps. Try running on a device.

And, if your goal is just to get the location and stop, don't use `startUpdatingLocation`; call `requestLocation`. That's what it's for.

Comment: Would it help you to see code that works? https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch22p773location/ch35p1032location/ViewController.swift

Comment: as for `requestLocation`, just added this in my edit, but I tried this and it still comes up as a failure. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/location/how-to-request-a-users-location-only-once-using-requestlocation I have a location set in the emulator, shouldn't that work? I'll try hooking up my iPhone though and see if its any different

Comment: Cool, please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Yea, the hackingwithswift example now works. As for that example, is it incomplete or are you not supposed to request authorization when you use request location?

Comment: The example is intended to show you how to request authorization. Look more carefully...